# Multinomial regression interpretation SPSS

Tags: interpretation, regression-coefficients, multinomial-distribution

-- start reading from the edited part -- 
When running a multinomial regression the two values we are really interested in are the values 'B' and B(Exp)'.

Let's say we have (fictive numbers):

- B: .098 ; B(Exp): 1.98
- B: -.098 ; B(Exp): 1.98

The B(Exp) is the same for both examples. But in one case the B is positive in the other negative. For the first I suppose it means the odds 'increase' by 1.98, but what about the second?

The odds 'decrease' by 1.98?

------ edited from here -----
(forget the above).
Clearly I should have been more specific. I will use actual numbers now. 
So let's assume I have a dependant variable D with three categories. And I have 2 explanatory variables E with 3 categories and sex with 2 categories. 
D:

- D1
- D2
- D3 (reference)

These are the results of parameter estimates in SPSS for the category D1:

E:

- E1: B= -.111 ; Exp(B)= .895
- E2: B= 2.264 ; Exp(B)= 9.622
- E3: (reference)

Sex:

- F: B= 1.514 ; Exp(B)= 4.546
- M: (reference)

Are the following statements correct?

- For females the odds of being in category D1 rather than in D3 'increase' by a factor 4.546 compared to males.
- For E1 the odds of being in category D1 rather than in D3 'decrease' by a factor .895 compared to E3.
- For E2 the odds of being in category D1 rather than in D3 'increase' by a factor 9.622 compared to E3.

In addition if the Exp(B) is lower than 1 it's decrease and otherwise increase? What statement would be correct for males?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "B(Exp)"?  This does not appear to be a standard name of anything and it makes no mathematical sense.

Comment: I meant Exp(B), anyways I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is impossible in your example , when $\beta$ is negative, your $exp(\beta)$ should be less than 1 but still bigger than zero. For example, $exp(-0.98)=0.3753111$. Which means your odds decreases by 37.5% or by 0.6246889 (relative to $1$) depending on different understanding of English. And the first one should be $exp(0.98)=2.66$ when coefficient is positve the odds should be bigger than one for multinominal logistic regression.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it seems I am completely off with my understanding of it, I edited the above, if you could have a look?